# Two columns in two rows with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn Bootstrap grid more. I am trying to get two columns in two rows in the middle of my page. 
So it should look like this:

[image: Example]

Here is what I got so far:

```html
  

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <div id="text1">
        <label>Text 1</label>
      </div>
      <div id="text2">
        <label>Text 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <div id="text3">
        <label>Text 3</label>
      </div>
      <div id="text4">
        <label>Text 4</label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But my elements are not in place where I want them.

Comment: Have you tried using flexbox?

Comment: @RajanBenipuri no I haven't.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri he is using Bootstrap 3 in case you haven't seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution in a fiddle: [Solution 1](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38942/)

*Now for the explanation of the problem:*

First you need to set specific columns. Keep in mind that Bootstrap has a grid of **12**. So your maximum can be **12** at all time. However, you don't need to have the **columns** fill the entire grid.

You can use something called **offset** which allows you to put empty space in your elements. Having the class `class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-sm-5 offset-1"` gives you a column with a value of `5` so you can actually position 2 columns and have space on the side.

I would suggest to go through the Bootstrap grid and play around in order to get a familiar feeling on how to manipulate it.
The style sheet `margin-left:25px; margin-top:25px;` gives you the space on the top and on the side of the columns themselves.

Comment: I have tried your code but it's not placed in the middle of my screen... :/ I am playing around with bootstrap grid and trying to figure it out but still haven't found solution to my problem. If you run my code snippet above you will see placement of elements same as when I run your code. @ZombieChowder

Comment: @dome I've updated the fiddle. Check out the **class thing** `.thing{
  margin-left:15%;
}` Adjust the margin however works best for your screen.